# how to store a file in android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i want to save a file in a sqlite android database , first of all i choose the file by a folder explorer that i already made it now im stuck how to save this file in the database and display it in another activity like a menu of files.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textview" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get File Name From SDCard"  
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"      
    />    
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">  
        <EditText
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:hint="EditText"
            android:id="@+id/editText" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" 
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" 
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/skipButton" >
        </EditText>

        <Button android:text="Browser"
             android:id="@+id/skipButton" 
             android:textSize="18dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:onClick="getfile" >
         </Button>
        <Button android:text="Enregistrer"
            android:id="@+id/saveB"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             >
</Button>
</RelativeLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Horrible idea, to bloat your database with files. You'd better store file paths.

Comment: Paths are nothing but strings.

Comment: it's not what i need , the files that i want to stor it contain link to web page

Comment: @Andro, check this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834620/cannot-open-sqlite-database-from-sqlite-helper-oncreate-when-oncreate-is-trigge/34838970#34838970

Comment: URLs are strings, like paths.

Comment: to be more clear , first activity will contain files and a small button to add a new files until now i made a file explorer but i dont know how to save the choosen files and display it again in the first activity

Answer (score 1):

You need to read your file in order to fill a byte array, then store it into a BLOB field in your db table.