# I get this error: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I get that error when I try to make sentences insert and select in my SQLite data base of my android code. Could someone give me any idea for solve this?

Code:

```
public boolean altaCliente(Clientes c) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Clientes VALUES ('" 
            + c.getNumero() 
            + "','" 
            + c.getNombre() + "','" 
            + c.getAlias() + "','" 
            + c.getGruPrecioCliente()
            + "','" 
            + c.getGruDesCliente() 
            + "','" 
            + c.getGruRegIvaNeg() + "') ");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: public boolean altaCliente(Clientes c) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Clientes VALUES ('" + c.getNumero() + "','" + c.getNombre() + "','" + c.getAlias() + "','"
                + c.getGruPrecioCliente() + "','" + c.getGruDesCliente() + "','" + c.getGruRegIvaNeg() + "') ");
        return true;
    }

Comment: This is an example where the aplication crashes, but I'm really sure that the problem isn't there. I think maybe it's due to some null field.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834620/cannot-open-sqlite-database-from-sqlite-helper-oncreate-when-oncreate-is-trigge/34838970#34838970

Comment: Maria, it's adviceable to accept an answer, when it solves your problem. Otherwise, your post will remain in the `Unanswered Question Queue` forever. See the white tickmark near the answer? Just check it, and it will become green.

Answer (score 0):

`MethodAndArgsCaller` tells you that you are passing wrong arguments to a method.
In this case, you arent passing all the required arguments to `execSQL()`.

Also mind that `execSQL()` doesn't retun any value, so it's absolutely useless to return true.

I'd rewrite your method like this:

```
public void altaCliente(Clientes c)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Clientes VALUES ('" + 
       c.getNumero() + "', '" + 
       c.getNombre() + "', '" + 
       c.getAlias() + "', '" + 
       c.getGruPrecioCliente() + "', '" + 
       c.getGruDesCliente() + "', '" +
       c.getGruRegIvaNeg() + "')", 
       null); // This is your missing parameter!
}
```

This solves the `MethodAndArgsCaller` exception only.

You might have more exceptions after solving that.

- I must think that all of your columns are **strings** (because you're inserting all strings!). If not, this can cause an exception.
- And that you're not trying to insert an AUTOINCREMENT field manually (`c.getNumero()`?). Or this would cause another exception.
- That your sentences don't contain any apostrophe (`'`), because I don't see any code where you **double** it if present. If you don't double apostrophes, this would cause another error.

Suggestion:

> Using **bound parameters** would be a better solution.